Why so many scientifically sane people are so ignorant in question about human consciousness?
Question in subject I guess clear enough, nothing to add into body.
Scientific sanity - we typically understand evidence based approach or Popper criteria.
Ignorance - Socrat described it in best way, and he never used it as insult.
Please give facts not an opinion in your answer.

Sanity and knowledge are two different things?

It varies country by country, but it seems most eduation systems cover extensively physics, math, biology, geology, chemistry, history, economics, etc but the research on conciousness is not part of the main curriculum. Anybody who graduates highschool has studied enough to be "scientifically sane" (at least, was given the chance), but knows nothing about consciousness. Probably, current research on consciousness is too specialized to be part of everyone's curriculum.

Perhaps it is a topic that makes no discernable difference in their lives? Paper or plastic? Rh+ or Rh-?

What does "ignorant" mean here? Does it mean something more substantial than "why don't more people agree with me?" - What set of beliefs constitute non-ignorance here?

Question in subject I guess clear enough, hum, no, not at all. What am I ignorant about? Why should it be given any time at all during a curriculum?

Ignorance doesn’t need to be explained more. Just ignorance in common sense. You can refer to wikipedia to definition of ignorance if you want. Downvote to this question - you can see as evidence that such ignorance is actually exists.

@ArtemS.Tashkinov “What am I ignorant about? Why should it be given any time at all during a curriculum?” Are you asking me - or you asking yourself? If you asking me - than you are an ignorant. If you asking yourself - than you asking right question yourself.

You fail to back your assumption, you fail to state what "question about human consciousness" is supposed to be, and you attack the community for not agreeing with your own thought, which you failed to express concisely. I think you should reconsider what you really want to achieve and what a good way to get there might be. Please start with a properly laid out question that is not a completely unsubstantiated assumption in disguise. You can edit this one and get it reopened.

@PhilipKlöcking if you know how to edit this question to make it valid, please  do it. Or you can send me that text, so I can paste it here. I am not attacking anyone here.

Unfortunately, you've completely evaded my questions. How could a course on such an elusive and ill-defined subject benefit people? You're throwing around "ignorance" as if you know a ton more about consciousness than people here and that this knowledge has really improved your life, which I really really doubt. The best philosophers and scientists in the world are more humble about the subject than you are, and they don't even have a definition of consciousness yet. Please read this article and stop being judgemental:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consciousness

I'm not into religions but boy I love this commandment: "Judge not, that ye be not judged."

@ArtemS.Tashkinov If I knew the answer, I wouldn’t be asking this question. Regarding “Ill defined subject”, “benefit people” - that’s in the best way to describe, what I mean be ignorant, no offense to anyone

@DmytroBrazhnyk I cannot help you as long as I do not even know what you mean by "question about consciousness". There are millions of questions about consciousness and one of the more trickier ones is what it is supposed to be in the first place.

@ArtemS.Tashkinov Scientific discovery made not for benefit. Searching the truth, that what makes us humans.

@ScottRowe The fact that sanity and knowledge is not the same, that what makes me concerned, and it describes ignorance of majority. To understand certain thing you need to be insane, because it open you mind, to things which could be true but not commonly accepted.

Consider looking in to Nonduality.

@ScottRowe right, non-duality. knowledge leads to ignorance, while ignorance leads us to new knowledge. That’s a loop, which makes ignorance and non-ignorance single whole.


Why so many scientifically sane people are so ignorant in question about human consciousness?

The cognitive sciences have an enormous amount of data on the brain and (a little less) on the mind, but scientists have broadly the same amount of data on subjective experience as non-scientists do, presumably because subjective experience doesn't lend itself to being tested empirically.
On subject matters where we have little or no data, imagination and prejudice are given a free ride, and opinions tend to spread wide. It makes little difference whether you are a scientist or not.

"Scientists" are in no way averse to holding forth authoritatively on subjects they know nothing about. Einstein has a lot of famous foolish quotes attributed to him.

@ScottRowe Yeah, we're only human, apparently.

Every one of us is "ignorant in question about human consciousness". I consider human consciousness to be the biggest unsolved problem in the world. In the field of science, it is possible to obtain definitive answers to questions, which then form the basis for the asking of further questions- and thus the field advances. This hasn't happened yet in the study of human consciousness.
BTW sanity has nothing to do with it.

Even though unsolved, we seem to have gotten along just fine without knowing more about it. People debate whether understanding it fully would have any effect on our daily lives. Same for Free Will and a lot of other "Unsolved Mysteries" That it is orthogonal to Sanity should tell us something :-)

+1 from Niels...

@ScottRowe "orthogonal to sanity"! I love it.
